# Jenkins and git building only the changed folders

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, microservices

I have a multibranch pipeline project in Jenkins. My Jenkins job mainly consists of building dotnet-core docker images and pushing them onto the docker repository then starting containers on a Jenkins slave using a compose file. In my VS solution file, I have 6-7 projects in separate folders. The number will increase. All of them are docker images that will run in containers.

At the moment, I use `dotnet publish` for each project then build the images using the compose file. The problem is, I need to build all of them even when there are no changes in the image. I want to build only the apps which are not changed. Is there a way for me to filter out the unchanged folders and build only them?

Comment: When someone does a commit, it triggers the job, right? If so, maybe you can figure out what files have changed, and based on that, you only build the projects that were affected?  I'm not familiar with VS solution files, but if the workspace is kept between builds, then VS Solution only builds the projects that are "dirty"?

Comment: Well, keeping workspace between builds might work but the deleted files are a problem in that case. Oddly, I had tried that on another project and workspace kept increasing in size when I opted not to clean it. That's probably because of the MSBuild's auto generated files. They just keep piling up as the project evolves. Finding out the changed folders between commits would work, albeit it takes too much scripting work though. 

Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I think it may sense to separate into different repositories and have different jenkins jobs for each one. 
Then you split your microservices architecture in different repositories and you can even test each microservices running the docker images for each microservice.

This is the way we are doing in my company. And for me, it looks better at the end, but it can be a big effort at the beginning.

Comment: We were actually doing that, then our client wanted us to use a single repository, now we are looking for a work-around. I agree, that may make more sense to separate repositories in a microservices architecture.